# Setup iptable with preventing ab -n 1000 -c 100

Tags: iptables

I would like to setup basic firewall rules with iptables.
The goal is to reject flood requests per IP. Like "ab -n 100000 -c 1000 "

There are only 2 rules:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -i eth0 -m state --state NEW -m limit --limit 100/s --limit-burst 10000 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -i eth0 -j LOG --log-prefix "__test__"
```

But I when grep iptables log with "sort" and "uniq -c" I see lot's of IPs like:

```
1 SRC=173.252.77.112
1 SRC=173.252.114.116
1 SRC=173.252.114.114
1 SRC=173.252.114.113
```

Is "-m state --state NEW" effect only new connections? Then why IPs with low requests count appeared in log?

Please advice.

Comment: This site is for programming questions. We are not general server/software tech support.

Comment: Very funny. See the "programming only" questions: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=iptables

Answer (score 0):

Finally the solution is:

```
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 80 -m hashlimit --hashlimit 1000/sec --hashlimit-burst 5000 --hashlimit-mode dstip --hashlimit-name hosts -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j REJECT
```

Do not block SE-crawlers packets and resists against http-flood like: ab -n 1000 -c 100 http://{host}/